# How to add custom emojis to discord.py 2.0 dropdown

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am trying to use a custom emoji from my dropdown but I don't know how?

I am using discord.py 2.0 btw

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out just use:

`<:emojiname:emojiid>`

When getting the emoji id do:

`\emojiname then you will get it!`